# How do I merge tags?

Tags: support, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

Example: azure-kubernetes and azure-aks, arm-template, and azure-template.

I don't see an option; I see a synonym option, but I need somebody to upvote the synonym (if it even achieves the same).

Comment: Note: both [azure-template] and [arm-template] have now been merged into the new tag [azure-rm-template], as of a more recent (and broader) proposal that includes that suggestion: [Microsoft Azure Collective launch and proposed tag changes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423231/1478931)

Comment: Also, it looks like [azure-kubernetes] was made a synonym of and merged into [azure-aks] – related discussions: [Synonymize \[azure-kubernetes\] with \[azure-aks\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404436/1478931), [Improve naming of the tag used for Azure Kubernetes Service](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405393/1478931), [The AKS tags need some attention](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/413598/1478931)

Comment: only took you 4.5 years

Answer (score 3):

To merge tags on Stack Exchange websites they must first be considered a tag synonym.To make a tag synonym someone (with minimum reputation points of 2,500 and at least 5 answer score on the tag). To be approved, tag synonym suggestions must have a net vote of 4 and never reach -2. After tags are considered tag synonyms a moderator can choose to merge the tags. This may take sometime for a moderator to get around to as there are plenty of things that need to be taken care of on this site and isn't done until mods are certain it is the best course of action.

Comment: yeah, i can read, but it never says anywhere that synonym = merge.

Comment: Sorry misunderstood your confusion. This MSE post better explains: [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work)

Comment: ok, but it doesnt explain how to merge tags

Comment: Only moderators can perform a merge

Comment: ok, thats worse. but how do I "force" a moderator to merge tags?

Comment: You can't force  a moderator to do a merge. The tags first must be synonyms and if the synonymizing of those tags does not cause any problems than Mods will likely get to merging it at some point.

Comment: @4c74356b41 a "merge" operation is mod only and effectively re-writes history... so if you want that to occur you need to make a convincing argument as to why it should be done, leave it a bit to reach some community consensus and discussion (if it's not an obvious - yeah, they should both be the same d0h!), and then a mod will review if that's been reached and action needs to be taken.

Comment: @4c74356b41 Synonym is really just making all the tags one main one. Note that i think you have five score at least for each of the tags you mentioned... you're an azure guru...

Comment: yeah, but I still need several other people to push the damn button