# Synonymize [azure-kubernetes] with [azure-aks]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The tags [azure-kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-kubernetes) and [azure-aks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-aks) is both used for [Azure Kubernetes Service - (AKS)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/kubernetes-service/).

Could we synonymize [azure-kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-kubernetes) with [azure-aks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-aks)? It already has 3 synonyme votes - but not many users are active on tag synonyms or have enough reputation. This naming is relatively consistent with [amazon-eks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-eks) that is used for Amazon Elastic Kubernetes Service. But if naming is a problem that could be changed, I think the main confusion is that there are two different tags for the same service.

Comment: I'm happy to rename [[tag:amazon-eks]] with an expanded name, too, if you think that would be preferable.

Comment: When looking at [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) beginning with `azure` most of them write the full name. I wonder if the tag should be `azure-kubernetes-service` similar to [[azure-web-apps-service]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-web-app-service) ? The corresponding service on Google has the tag [[google-kubernetes-engine]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-kubernetes-engine). While I think `amazon-eks` is good because it is consistent with other AWS-tags like [[amazon-ecs]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ecs).

Comment: Yeah, we prefer the full name when possible. In the early days, there were significant character length limitations on tag names, so it wasn't always possible. Nowadays, the limit has been extended, so it's usually possible to have the full product name in there, unless the name is truly something unwieldy, in which case, it wouldn't make sense anyway. Putting consistency with existing tags aside (since this can be changed), can you update the question or post an answer with the tags that you would propose to rename?

Comment: @CodyGray I posted an answer with the suggested name change.

Comment: @CodyGray perhaps it is easier to have the synonym in the other direction, e.g. `azure-aks` -> `azure-kubernetes` and then rename it to `azure-kubernetes-service` then will users find it whatever tag they try to use?

Comment: Related: [Improve naming of the tag used for Azure Kubernetes Service](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405393/1478931) – and also: [The AKS tags need some attention](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/413598/1478931)

Answer (score 4):

> The tags `azure-kubernetes` and `azure-aks` is both used for Azure Kubernetes Service - (AKS).

> It already has 3 synonyme votes

Getting this under a common tag was good.

### Naming

[Azure Kubernetes Service - (AKS)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/kubernetes-service/) is known both as "Azure Kubernetes Service" but also just "AKS" (corresponding to "GKE" for "Google Kubernetes Engine").

This is now under the tag `azure-aks` - the problem with that tag name is that "a" in "aks" also stands for "azure", so it is almost as saying "azure-azure-kubernetes-service".

I suggest that the tag [azure-aks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-aks) should be named `azure-kubernetes-service` similar to [google-kubernetes-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-kubernetes-engine).

As a footnote, this is the name that is in use on DevOps Stackexhange: [azure-kubernetes-service](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/azure-kubernetes-service)