# Improve naming of the tag used for Azure Kubernetes Service

Tags: support, tags

There were multiple tags in use for [Azure Kubernetes Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-en/services/kubernetes-service/) and then [azure-kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-kubernetes) [was synonymized to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404436/synonymize-azure-kubernetes-with-azure-aks) [azure-aks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-aks) - under one tag.

### Naming

[Azure Kubernetes Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-en/services/kubernetes-service/) is sometimes also referred to by only using **AKS** - where **A** stands for **Azure**. But the current tag is [azure-aks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-aks) - with both using "Azure" written out and A (for Azure) in the acronym.

I propose that a tag with the full name `azure-kubernetes-service` is a better name. This is similar to e.g. [azure-web-app-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-web-app-service) or [google-kubernetes-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-kubernetes-engine)

Comment: Related: [Synonymize \[azure-kubernetes\] with \[azure-aks\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404436/1478931) – and also: [The AKS tags need some attention](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/413598/1478931)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the [synonymization](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404436/synonymize-azure-kubernetes-with-azure-aks) could be changed to the other direction: `azure-aks` -> `azure-kubernetes`.

And then the tag `azure-kubernetes` could be renamed to `azure-kubernetes-service`.