# The AKS tags need some attention

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonym-process

Just came across the AKS tag(s) and they look a bit all over the place. The most popular tag is [azure-aks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-aks) which doesn't make much sense, since AKS stands for *Azure Kubernetes Service*, so that's *Azure Azure Kubernetes Service*. The second most popular one is [aks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aks) which should probably be made a synonym. I don't have any reputation in these tags. Neither of the tags has a description of usage guidance.

For me, it seems like the right tag for this should be [azure-kubernetes-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-kubernetes-service)? not sure what the process is for this kind of thing?

Comment: I believe you mean _kubern**e**tes Service_ ? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/kubernetes-service/

Comment: Yep, my Greek could use some work :D

Comment: I think you have sufficient rep to edit tag info, no?

Comment: I can edit the tag wiki. But my point is, the tags themselves are "wrong". I can't add synonyms as I don't have rep in those tags

Comment: "Azure Azure Kubernetes Service" is ok. Have you never heard "Amazon Amazon Web Services" (Amazon AWS)? :)

Comment: Related: [Synonymize \[azure-kubernetes\] with \[azure-aks\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404436/1478931), [Improve naming of the tag used for Azure Kubernetes Service](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405393/1478931)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[azure-aks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-aks) is fine as-is ([that's more or less what Microsoft calls it](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/kubernetes-service/)). It seems odd from an acronym standpoint, but it fits the nomenclature of the other Azure tags. [aks] is now merged with the other tag.

Comment: For the sake of comparison, the tag for EKS is `amazon-eks`, and the tag for GKE is `google-kubernetes-engine`. That would make it one similar to `azure-aks`, one similar to `azure-kubernetes-service`, and zero similar to `aks`.

Comment: Microsoft calls it "AKS" or "Azure Kubernetes Service"; they don't call it "Azure AKS". I would recommend renaming it to [tag:microsoft-aks] with [tag:azure-kubernetes-service] and [tag:aks] as synonyms.

Comment: I should note that [azure-kubernetes] is already a synonym. For completeness I did add [azure-kubernetes-service] as another synonym. It makes no sense to call this [microsoft-aks], since every other Azure tag is [azure-*]